# Unable to change file mode on bin: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, macos, terminal, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer globally on Mac OS.

I tried to move the composer.phar file by using this command in Terminal as instructed in the Getting Started section:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

I get this error:

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/bin/composer: No such file or
directory
```

When I try create the directory it says the operation is not permitted:

```
bash-3.2# mkdir -p /usr/bin/composer mkdir: /usr/bin/composer:
Operation not permitted
```

I even tried to navigate to the "bin" directory and it says:

```
bash-3.2# mkdir composer mkdir: composer: Operation not permitted
```

I've enabled root successfully but still I try and alter the permissions:

```
bash-3.2# chmod ugo+rwx "bin" chmod: Unable to change file mode on
bin: Operation not permitted bash-3.2#
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses!

When I type the following command:

```
ls -leO@d /usr/local/bin
```

It prints:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username staff  - 2212003 27 Mar 17:00 /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background: `/usr/bin` is generally for "standard" binaries, not things you install yourself; those generally belong someplace like `/usr/local/bin`. In recent versions of macOS, this is enforced by [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) and by keeping "system" files/directories on [a separate, read-only volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834865/unable-to-change-file-mode-on-bin-operation-not-permitted).

The problem: It looks like on your system, there's a file named `/usr/local/bin` rather than a directory. This can happen if some installer tries to install a program to `/usr/local/bin` (e.g. with `mv someprogram /usr/local/bin`) without first making sure a directory by that name exists.

How to solve it: The first thing to do is to move/rename whatever file got installed as `/usr/local/bin`, and then create it as a directory:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin-moved
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

Once that's straightened out, you should be able to install composer normally. According to [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) (and adding `sudo` to get access to the directory), you'd do that with:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Finally, if you want to, you can try to figure out what program got installed as (rather than *in*) `/usr/local/bin`. Or just delete the `/usr/local/bin-moved` file and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin` is a protected system folder. Do *not* change its permissions.

Instead install it somewhere else, e.g. into `/usr/local/bin`. You may still need to run the copy command with `sudo` though: `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`